# Referring to a variable in a list of data frames in an lapply

Tags: r, function, lapply

I would like to produce frequency tables for various subgroups of my data. The data looks as follows:

```
school <- c(rep(1, 20), rep(2,20))
class <- c(rep(1,10), rep(2,10), rep(1,10), rep(2,10))
female <- sample(0:1, 40, replace=TRUE)
age <- sample(12:13, 40, replace=TRUE)
data <- data.frame(school, class, female, age)
```

There are 2 schools, and each school has 2 classes. My goal is to get a function that allows me to produce a frequency table for a specified variable for each school. The table within each school should include the frequencies of a given variable for the entire school, as well as for each class within the school. It should look like this (example variable *female*):

```
 Female  0  1
 school 10 10
 Class1  8 12
 Class2 11  9
```

I have tried to first program a function, and then use *lapply* to get a separate table for each school. Specifically, what I have tried is

```
dist <- function(data, var) {
f_all <- table(data$var)
f_class <- table(data$class, data$var)
freq <- rbind(f_all, f_class)
return(freq)
}

data_test <- split(data, school)
a <- lapply(data_test, dist, var="age")
```

When I apply this code I get an error message

```
"Error in table(data$class, data$var)) : 
 all arguments must have the same length"
```

My guess is that I fail to properly use the variable name as a function argument. I have tried without quotation marks, but with the same result. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Try replacing `data$var` in your function with `data[[var]]`.

Comment: This is a frequently asked question... "why does "$" fail inside functions". You should read the help page for `?"$"` carefully, then re-read it carefully, then read it again carefully. Then wait a week, and then repeat. The proper use of the extraction functions is critical to learning R.

Comment: Thanks, both, for taking the time to answer, and thanks aosmith, for a constructive help. BondedDust: I did consult the search on this page, and, funny enough, I put in the exact sentence you wrote ("why does "$" fail inside functions"), and got NO hits. It seems that in my future questions I will have to add a sentence "I did consult the search function, but did not get a good result" in order to receive a constructive answer.